# How to install php 7.0.4 in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, magento, php7

I am running Magento2 using php7 I updated php to 7.0.5 but Magento2 has a known issue with this version. How can I install version 7.0.4 specifically?

I installed it using ppa:ondrej/php and apt-get by the way.

Comment: Contact Magento developers for the fix.

Comment: I did but they have not fixed it yet, and they can take months to solve it